# "Иду на вы" — происхождение выражения

Tags: фразеология

"Иду на вы" — то есть, иду сражаться. А почему "на вы"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А что Вас смущает? Значение или падежная форма?
"Вы" - древнейшая форма винительного падежа, тут все нормально. Правда тут есть одна хитрость, эта форма изначально не могла быть энклитичной, т.е. произносилась всегда с ударением, но еще на стадии ранней письменности потеряла это свойство. Т.е. употребление её всегда было подчеркнуто архаично.

Значение тоже понятно - объявление войны. В более поздний период сказали бы, возможно, "Иду войной на вас".

Что касается происхождения, то известность связывают с легендарной фразой князя Святослава, который, согласно Нестору, передал (или передавал) её врагам: «посылаше къ странамъ глаголя: хочю на вы ити». Но, как уже сказал, сама форма крылатой фраза скорее всего более древняя. И Святослав скорее всего воспользовался обычной формулой.

http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%8B

Comment: У вас из Лаврентьевской летописи цитата. Из контекста описываются обычный порядок похода Святослава с дружиной, как они ели, как они спали, как и куда в походы ходили. 

[Ипатьевская летопись](http://www.lrc-lib.ru/rus_letopisi/Ipatius/gif_mm.php?file=053-054.gif) (см. начало)
[Лаврентьевская летопись](http://expositions.nlr.ru/LaurentianCodex/_Project/page_Show.php) (год 6472)

Comment: Спасибо, конечно...
Вы бы хоть страницу указали...  С моим интернетом все картинки подряд рассматривать - мало не покажется.  
Впрочем, и так видно, что в переводе деепричастие идет на месте оригинального имперфекта и аориста. Так что для меня вопрос открыт, было ли это (по сетописи) сказано разово, конкретному врагу, или же, как многие трактуют, говорилось постоянно.

Comment: стр 53 4-я строчка сверху в Ипатьевской, лист 19 в Лавреньтьевской. Картинку можно отключить.

Comment: Спасибо. Зачем отключать то, ради чего я туда полез?! ))))

Answer (score 5):

Это из летописи. По легенде князь Святослав Игоревич, когда шёл на печенегов и др. кочевников, предупреждал их, - "Иду на вы (вас)", чтобы те вышли его встречать и генеральное сражение состоялось раньше. "Вы" здесь, старая форма "вас", в древнерусском языке винительный падеж совпадал с именительным.

Comment: > в древнерусском языке винительный падеж совпадал  
  
Это не так, даже если говорить только про местоимения. Что касается формы  "ВЫ", то она праславянская по происхождению, но уже в древнерусский период начала активно вытесняться более современной формой. 
У Хабургаева об этом - параграф 201 и далее.

Comment: Фразу про древнерусский взял [отсюда](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_wingwords/1053/%D0%98%D0%B4%D1%83) вполне допускаю, что это и не так.

>передал её половцам...

Святослав с половцами не воевал, они появились у границ Руси примерно через век, после его смерти. Ели не затруднит исправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: >Святослав с половцами не воевал,   
  
Согласен. С печенегами. Но я не имел в виду конкретный народ. 
Меня больше волнует, почему Нестор не написал какому именно врагу князь посылал это послание.  Другими словами, было ли это разовой акцией или, как обычно интерпретируют, дкелплал это постоянно. Я в последнем крепко сомневаюсь. У Нестора форма имперфекта (посылаше), что ставит под сомнение многократность действия. Хотя сама по себе фраза вызывает вопросы. Форма "глаголя" не могла быть написана Нестором, современные деепричастия появились шесть-семь столетий спустя.

Comment: Надо смотреть из какой именно летописи у вас фраза. В любом случае, ПВЛ дошло до нас в списках, самый ранний из которых (Лаврентьевская летопись) датируется 1377 годом. Вечером смогу посмотреть вашу фразу конкретней, если интересно.

Comment: Да то-то и оно, что все - из "третьих перьев". 
У меня - из Википедии ))) Но другого варианта нигде и не встречал.
Про Лавреньевкую летопись я толком не знаю, она вроде считается списком с более ранней, но все равно сомнительно. Но в любом случае, язык уже явно не эпохи Святослава.
Ипатьевская же летопись - это же другая историческо-лингвистическая эпоха. Если не ощибаюсь, аорист уже начал утрачиваться в пользу современных форм прошедшего времени (родом их древнего перфекта).
Ну посмотрите, если не лениво. Хотя вряд ли что добавит...

Comment: >чтобы те вышли его встречать и генеральное сражение состоялось раньше

 Суть не в "раньше", я полагаю, а в том, что Святослав был так храбр и самоуверен, что не делал засад, не устраивал неожиданных облав, а заранее предупреждал врага о своих намерениях.

Comment: @Пересвет, нет, суть именно в том, чтобы противник вышел на генеральное сражение, и вместо изнурительной партизанской войны с каждым кочевьем, было бы лишь одно генеральное сражение. Византийцев или хазар о грядущих походах Святослав не предупреждал.